# What does this symbol mean in set theory? c/=

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Symbol in question
[image]
I've been looking all over for what this means but everything I've seen is just the regular A ⊆ B for A is a subset of B. I'm confused on the difference between these two symbols.

Context: Around 4:50 of [this introductory lecture on topological spaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wyOoLUjUeI&list=PLU18-eJyqc0SWNe_nJtY8Ucm3hGgS8D9T&index=4). I just typed this up in photoshop and made a jpg. It should look like ⊆ but with an = instead of - underneath it. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: I would read it as I would $\subseteqq$ and thus the same as $\subseteq$ -- "subset, or equal to". I've sometimes seen the comparable notations $\le$ and $\leqq$ for instance. Though the small "c" gives me doubts, but it could be poor typesetting.

Comment: You should show more context of where this comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did in Photoshop is not the symbol. Schuller writes on the board $C \subseteqq \mathcal{O}$ to mean a collection of open sets. Here $\subseteqq$ should be interpreted as $\subseteq.$

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify if there's a definitional difference between ⫅ and ⊆ in general? Or is that relation context dependent?

Comment: I find no difference. Cf. $\leq$ and $\leqq.$